# How to only include directory contents in Azure Publish Artifact without full filepath?

Tags: azure, cicd

I've been using Azure Pipelines and Releases to build and publish artifacts.

In SolutionX, there are projects ProjectY and ProjectYTests.

I build everything in the solution (to run the tests) and then I want to publish just ProjectY's built contents, in an artifact called drop.

I deploy it to a folder called FolderZ.

When I download the published artifact, the filepath is like: `FolderZ/drop/ProjectY/bin/Release/*`.
I'd much rather it was just `FolderZ/*`.

How can I get rid of (at least) the bin/Release pipeline bit?

Answer (score 2):

In the copy files task, there is an optional parameter flattenFiles (bool). This does the job.